# How to show alert messages with the buttons in "Change List" page in Django Admin?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-admin

There is `Person` model as shown below:

```py
# "app1/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And, there is `Person` admin as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_per_page = 3
    list_display_links = None
    ordering = ('id',)
```

And, there is **Change List** page for `Person` admin as shown below:

[image]

Then, an alert message is shown after changing the first or last names, then clicking on `Go` button as shown below:

[image]

So now, how can I show the same alert message after changing the first or last names, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons as shown below:

[image]

In addition, an alert message is shown after not changing the first or last names and selecting **an Admin Action**, then clicking on `Save` button as shown below:

[image]

And, another alert message is shown after changing the first or last names and selecting **an Admin Action**, then clicking on `Save` button as shown below:

[image]

So now again, how can I show the same 2 alert messages after not changing or changing the first or last names, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons as shown below:

[image]

[image]

So, how can I do them?

Answer (score 0):

You can show alert messages with the buttons in only one **Change List** admin page or all **Change List** admin pages. *I don't know how to do this in all **Change List** admin pages in only one app.

First, I explain how to show alert messages with the buttons in only one **Change List** admin page.

For example, copy [actions.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/actions.js) from `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/actions.js` in your virtual environment to `core/static/core/admin/app1/js/` to add CSS Selectors to it as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-static
 |     └-core
 |        └-admin
 |           └-app1 
 |              └-js
 |                 └-actions.js # Here
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 └-app2
```

Then, replace `admin/js/actions.js` with `core/admin/app1/js/actions.js` in the overridden [media()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#media-as-a-dynamic-property) in `Person` admin as shown below. *Setting both `actions.js` files to `js` in the overridden `media()` causes conflict and you can see the original [media()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L746) which has no css and 8 `js` files by default:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django import forms

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_per_page = 3
    list_display_links = None
    ordering = ('id',)

    @property
    def media(self):
        extra = "" if settings.DEBUG else ".min"
        js = [
            "admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery%s.js" % extra,
            "admin/js/jquery.init.js",
            "admin/js/core.js",
            "admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js",
            # "admin/js/actions.js", # Replaced
            "core/admin/app1/js/actions.js", # With this
            "admin/js/urlify.js",
            "admin/js/prepopulate.js",
            "admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp%s.js" % extra,
        ]
        return forms.Media(js=js)
```

Then first, replace `document.querySelector(...)` code with `document.querySelectorAll(...)` code as shown below to show the same alert message after changing the first or last names, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons:

```js
# "core/static/core/admin/app1/js/actions.js"

// document.querySelector('#changelist-form button[name=index]').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//     if (list_editable_changed) {
//         const confirmed = confirm(gettext("You have unsaved changes on individual editable fields. If you run an action, your unsaved changes will be lost."));
//         if (!confirmed) {
//             event.preventDefault();
//         }
//     }
// });

document.querySelectorAll(
    `#changelist-form button[name=index],
     #changelist-form a[href*="?p="],
     #changelist-form a.showall,
     .object-tools a.addlink`
).forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (list_editable_changed) {
            const confirmed = confirm(gettext("You have unsaved changes on individual editable fields. If you run an action, your unsaved changes will be lost."));
            if (!confirmed) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then, the same alert message is shown after changing the first or last names, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons as shown below:

[image]

Then next, replace `const el = document.querySelector(...)` code with `const els = document.querySelectorAll(...)` code as shown below to show the same 2 alert messages after not changing or changing the first or last names, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons:

```js
# "core/static/core/admin/app1/js/actions.js"

// const el = document.querySelector('#changelist-form input[name=_save]');
// // The button does not exist if no fields are editable.
// if (el) {
//     el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//         if (document.querySelector('[name=action]').value) {
//             const text = list_editable_changed
//                 ? gettext("You have selected an action, but you haven’t saved your changes to individual fields yet. Please click OK to save. You’ll need to re-run the action.")
//                 : gettext("You have selected an action, and you haven’t made any changes on individual fields. You’re probably looking for the Go button rather than the Save button.");
//             if (!confirm(text)) {
//                 event.preventDefault();
//             }
//         }
//     });
// }

const els = document.querySelectorAll(
    `#changelist-form input[name=_save], 
        #changelist-form a[href*="?p="],
        #changelist-form a.showall,
        .object-tools a.addlink`
);
// The button does not exist if no fields are editable.
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i]) {
        els[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (document.querySelector('[name=action]').value) {
                const text = list_editable_changed
                    ? gettext("You have selected an action, but you haven’t saved your changes to individual fields yet. Please click OK to save. You’ll need to re-run the action.")
                    : gettext("You have selected an action, and you haven’t made any changes on individual fields. You’re probably looking for the Go button rather than the Save button.");
                if (!confirm(text)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, the same 2 alert messages are shown after not changing or changing the first or last names and selecting **an Admin Action**, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Next, I explain how to show alert messages with the buttons in all **Change List** admin pages.

So, set `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates', # Here
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then, copy [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-static
 |     └-core
 |        └-admin
 |           └-app1 
 |              └-js
 |                 └-actions.js
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-base.html # Here
```

Then, remove `"admin/js/actions.js"` from `js` in the overridden `media()` not just in `Person` admin but also in all other admins as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person, Animal, Food
from django import forms

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_per_page = 3
    list_display_links = None
    ordering = ('id',)

    @property
    def media(self):
        extra = "" if settings.DEBUG else ".min"
        js = [
            "admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery%s.js" % extra,
            "admin/js/jquery.init.js",
            "admin/js/core.js",
            "admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js",
            # "admin/js/actions.js", # Here
            "admin/js/urlify.js",
            "admin/js/prepopulate.js",
            "admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp%s.js" % extra,
        ]
        return forms.Media(js=js)

@admin.register(Animal)
class AnimalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    @property
    def media(self):
        js = [
            # ...
            # "admin/js/actions.js", # Here
            # ...
        ]
    # ...

@admin.register(Food)
class FoodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    @property
    def media(self):
        js = [
            # ...
            # "admin/js/actions.js", # Here
            # ...
        ]
    # ...
```

Then in `base.html`, add `<script ... 'core/admin/app1/js/actions.js' ...></script>` after `<link ... "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">` as shown below, then the same alert message can be shown after changing the first or last names, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons in all **Change List** admin pages and the same 2 alert messages can be shown after not changing or changing the first or last names and selecting **an Admin Action**, then clicking on **page numbers'**, `Show all` or `ADD PERSON` buttons in all **Change List** admin pages:

```
# "templates/admin/base.html"

# ...
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
<script src="{% static 'core/admin/app1/js/actions.js' %}" defer></script> {# Here #}
{% block dark-mode-vars %}
# ...
```